# Hide Keyboard when DatePicker is selected - issues not resolved

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, datepicker

Ok so I've gone through pretty much all the SO articles on this subject and can't resolve my particular situation.  I have a view controller with 3 text fields and a text area.  One of the text fields is for a date.  When the user enters this field, I want to hide the keyboard and show the date picker.

The issue I run into with my code so far is that the keyboard shows up when I enter any of the fields, but then does not disappear no matter what I've tried.

I could not find any sample app that has this feature and would like some direction on how to resolve this issue.

UPDATE: I fixed the first part of this and now can hide my keyboard when I get to the date field.

[image: Here is what it looks like when I click on the date field]

This was using the below code:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```

{

```
if ( textField.tag == 1 )
{

    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];

    [lblDesc2 resignFirstResponder];
    [lblTitle resignFirstResponder];
    [lblExcerpt resignFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"The method was called for textField ");

    [self showDatePicker];
    return NO;
}
else
{
    return YES;
}

}
```

Now what I need to do is pull up the date picker and here is my code for that which is not working yet:

```
- (void) showDatePicker{

CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,250,325,0);

datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:)               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

[scrollView addSubview:datePicker];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

[datePicker release]; 


}
```

.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "QuoteViewController.h"
    #import "SubjectViewController.h"
    #import "CategoryViewController.h"

    @class Quote, SubjectViewController, QuoteViewController;

    @interface AddQuoteViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{

    @private
        UIDatePicker *datePicker;
        UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;    // this button appears only when the date picker is open
        NSArray *dataArray;
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter;

        IBOutlet UITextField *lblTitle;
        IBOutlet UITextField *lblDesc2;
        IBOutlet UITextField *lblDate;
        IBOutlet UITextView *lblExcerpt;
        IBOutlet UITextField *lblNote;
        QuoteViewController *qvc;
        SubjectViewController *svc;
        //UITextField *editingField;
        IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;

    }


    @property (nonatomic, retain) UIScrollView *scrollView;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker; 
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *dataArray; 
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter; 

    //- (IBAction)doneAction:(id)sender;    // when the done button is clicked
    //- (IBAction)dateAction:(id)sender;    // when the user has changed the date picke values (m/d/y)

    @property (nonatomic,assign) QuoteViewController *qvc;
    @property (nonatomic,assign) SubjectViewController *svc;

    @end
```

.m

```
    #import "AddQuoteViewController.h"
    #import "Category.h"
    #import "QuotesAppDelegate.h"
    #import "Quote.h"
    #import "QuoteMap.h"


    @implementation AddQuoteViewController

    @synthesize svc, qvc;
    @synthesize datePicker, doneButton, dataArray, dateFormatter, scrollView;


    // Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view.
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        self.title = @"Add Quote";

        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                  initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel 
                                                   target:self action:@selector(cancel_Clicked:)] autorelease];

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                   initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemSave 
                                                   target:self action:@selector(save_Clicked:)] autorelease];

        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];

        self.dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
        [self.dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        [self.dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];

        CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0,250,325,0);

        datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];
        [datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(pickerChanged:)               forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

        [scrollView addSubview:datePicker];

        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;

        datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;

        lblDate.tag = 1;

        [datePicker release]; 

     }


    - (void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];

        //Set the textboxes to empty string.

        //Display the selected quote.
        lblExcerpt.text = @"";
        lblTitle.text = @"";
        lblDesc2.text = @"";
        lblDate.text = @"";

        NSLog(@"AddQuoteViewController initialized...");

        //Make the Category name textfield to be the first responder.
    //  [lblTitle becomeFirstResponder];
    }


    - (void)pickerChanged:(id)sender
    {

        NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
        lblDate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                          [df stringFromDate:datePicker.date]];

        NSLog(@"value: %@",[sender date]);
    }


- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

if ( textField.tag == 1 )
{

    [self.view endEditing:TRUE];

    [lblDesc2 resignFirstResponder];
    [lblTitle resignFirstResponder];
    [lblExcerpt resignFirstResponder];

    NSLog(@"The method was called for textField ");

    [self showDatePicker];
    return NO;
}
else
{
    return YES;
}
}
    - (void)viewDidUnload
    {
        self.dataArray = nil;
        self.dateFormatter = nil;
    }



    - (void)dealloc {
        [lblTitle release];
        [lblDesc2 release];
        [lblDate release];
        [lblExcerpt release];
        [doneButton release];
        [dataArray release];
        [scrollView release];
        [datePicker release];
        [dateFormatter release];
        [super dealloc];
    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

 //do what you want to do when user is touching the textfield. e.g. Display the DatePicker 

       return NO;

}
```

Comment: Thanks and this fixed the first part of the problem.  Now I need to pull up my date picker which isn't displaying, just a blank grey background behind where the keyboard was ...

Comment: CGRectMake(0,250,325,0); should be (0,0,320, 250)

Comment: Ok I posted a screen shot.  I also tried the above fix.  Unfortunately it still didn't display the date picker.

Comment: Seems like it may be something wrong with this line:     [scrollView addSubview:datePicker];

Comment: yeah, I tried showDatePicker. It works. Make sure your scroll view is visible on screen.

Comment: How do I verify that?  Other things that are part of the scrollView are still visible such as the other textfields...

Comment: change your Scrollview background color to red for debugging. also try "[self.view addSubview:datePicker]"

Comment: Wow you are awesome.  First, my scroll view was not fully extended so it wasn't showing the location where I wanted my date picker anyway.  But when I extended it fully, it still didn't work, however what did work was the self.view addSubView:datePicker! 

Not sure why the other way didn't work. But thank you immensely for helping me with this!

Comment: you are welcome. We are all here getting help and offering help. It is fun, coding!